# Returning a function if specific conditions are not followed

Tags: c#

Is it possible to not execute functionC if conditions are not followed in functionA?

```
public void functionA()
{
    if(!specificCondition)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public void functionB()
{
    functionA();/*Conditions did not meet so i no longer want the next 
    function to execute anymore */
    functionC();  
}

public void functionC()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Comment: Change `functionA` to return a `bool` as to whether or not to run `functionC`.

Comment: You can return `bool` from `functionA` and then you `if(functionA()){ functionC(); }`

Comment: Or call your functionC in functionA after the if condition

Comment: @KingoftheNorth I'm assuming he doesn't want functionC to always be called inside of functionA, otherwise there would be no purpose for functionB.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 the functionC has the objective to output "OK" to the console. Im assuming that this method is being used to alert the user that things went ok or something. Up to OP to define his use case

Comment: Can functionA throw excpetions? If so, should functionC be executed anyway so long the conditions are met? Or really if functionA actually ran, only (regardless of why or why not)?

Comment: Also: shouldn't `functionA` and `functionC` be private, so `functionB` is the Facade for calling them? Otherwise users could call functionC and functionA independently from each other, completely messing up their dependency on the call-order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return a bool from functionA

```
public bool functionA()
{
    if(!specificCondition)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void functionB()
{
    if(!functionA())
        functionC();  
}

public void functionC()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Comment: Isn't that back to front - when conditions not met in A, then C is not run.

Comment: @PaulF OP did say if conditions are not met in funcA then funcC should not run

Comment: @someguy76  That's what I am pointing out - in the above code functionA returns true if the condtions are NOT met - thus allows function to run. If the conditions are met, then it returns false, stopping function being run.

Comment: @PaulF Maybe. My point is about how to use function returning boolean. Author can figure out himself to flip bool if needed.

Comment: @PaulF I see, well the `!` will make it work depending on what the OP needs the condition to do.

Comment: Seems like you could return `true` when the condition is `true` and then you wouldn't need any nots.

Comment: Or _"public bool functionA() {     if(specificCondition) { ..... } return specificCondition; }"_

Answer (score 6):

Sure, check the condition before you call them:

```
public void functionB()
{
    if(specificCondition)
        functionA(); 
    if(specificCondition)
        functionC();  
}
```

Another option is to return a `bool` which you could check before you call the next method.

Comment: Condition is inside `functionA`. I mean calling `functionA()` doesn't need the check, only calling `functionC()` does.

Comment: @Sinatr: 1) it seems it is a class member because OP doesn't show that it's a local variable 2) If it's a local variable he needs to make it a class member anyway

Comment: Ah, now I got it, you also propose to remove condition from `functionA()`, right?

Comment: @Sinatr: Yes, it seems to be cleaner if its not in the method. Only if `functionA` will check this condition and sets the `bool`-property to `true` or `false` you need to call `functionA` without `if(specificCondition)`-check

Comment: Assuming the functionA does not change the value of specificCondition - then you don't need two if statements.

Comment: @PaulF: something could change this value between the first and the second call, for example another thread. I can't assume what i don't know. If the condition is a simple `bool` property it doesn't hurt to check it twice.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: OP did say that if functionA does not run then functionC should not run - so following that information only a single check would be needed. If the condition does change, then there would be the possibility that functionC would run even if functionA did not which he seems to be trying to avoid. Just my way of reading the question.

Comment: _"if functionA does not run then functionC should not run"_ doesn't that also imply A and C should be `private` ? Because this is only taken care of by functionB. But nobody stops me from calling them independently if they are public.

Comment: @PaulF: where did OP say that _"if functionA does not run then functionC should not run"_? He said that he doesn't want to execute functionC if the condition wasn't  met in functionA.

Comment: _"Is it possible to not execute functionC if conditions are not followed in functionA"_ - they way I read it is if the condition fails in functionA then functionC should not run. Your solution actually checks the condition outside of functionA - which may not be the correct thing to do.

Comment: @PaulF: well, the first what he does in functionA is to check this condition. As it stands, it could be outside. But i've already comented above that you need to call the method if it will modify the bool-property. Then the first check is wrong. Read my comment which was an answer to Sinatr's question.

Answer (score 1):

I should make clear that returning a boolean condition from the functions is the correct way to proceed.  If, however, you find yourself in a situation where you can't change either the parameters or the return type of the other methods, you can use a class-level variable.

```
class myClass
{
      var specificCondition = false;

    public void functionA()
    {
        var resultOfThisMethod = specificCondition;
        /*do stuff
        *
        *
        */
         if(resultOfThisMethod != testedcondition) 
              specificCondition = false;
    }

    public void functionB()
    {
        functionA();/*Conditions did not meet so i no longer want the next 
        function to execute anymore */
        specificCondition ? functionC() : return;  
    }

    public void functionC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }



}
```

Comment: _"I should make clear that returning a boolean condition from the functions is **the correct way** to proceed."_ - Well, there are other _correct_ ways, too.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope this Code will help you... In this we can get
>   `specificCondition` from functionA as ref and used in functionB to
>   take decision to functionC.

Using Ref

```
public void functionA(ref bool cond)
        {
            cond = specificCondition;
            if (!specificCondition)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        public void functionB()
        {
            bool cond = false;
            functionA(ref cond);

            if (cond)
            {
                functionC();
            }
        }

        public void functionC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }
```

Using Out.

```
public static void functionA(out bool cond)
            {
        bool specificCondition = true;
                cond = specificCondition;
                if (!specificCondition)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }

            public static void functionB()
            {
                bool cond;
                functionA(out cond);

                if (cond)
                {
                    functionC();
                }
            }

            public static void functionC()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            }
```

Comment: What benefit does this have over just changing the return type of functionA to Boolean?

Comment: May be he did not want to return anything from this method

Comment: By using the ref, you are essentially still returning a bool from this method. Even if functionA returns a bool, it can be called as if it returned void, like `functionA();`

Comment: Also I think you meant `out` and not `ref` since the OP wants to pass out the value, not take in a value that they can also change.